# PowerShell Scheduled Task RegisterTask Method

Tags: object, powershell, com, task, scheduler

I am attempting to use powershell v2.0 to create a scheduled task using the Schedule.Service Com Object. 
I have created ps1 file but we get an error when we execute it that is eluding me. 
Here is the code:

```
param(
    [string]$xmlFilePath = $(throw "-xmlFilePath is required"),
    [string]$server = "localhost",
    [string]$taskFolderName = "\"
)

try {
    $xmlContent = [xml] (Get-Content $xmlFilePath);    
    $taskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
    $taskScheduler.Connect($server) 
    $taskFolder = $taskScheduler.GetFolder($taskFolderName);
    $taskFolder.RegisterTask($xmlFilePathl, $xmlContent, 6, "<user name>", "<password>", 1);
}
catch {
    $Exception = $_.Exception;
    while ($Exception.Message -ne $null)
    {   
       Write-Error $Exception.Message;
       $Exception = $Exception.InnerException;
    }
    return; 
}
```

Runnig this locally or remotely gives the same result.
The error is as follows:
C:\temp\CreateScheduledTaskFromXML.ps1 : Exception calling "RegisterTask" with "6" argument(s): "(1,2)::"
At line:1 char:33
+ .\CreateScheduledTaskFromXML.ps1 <<<<  -server DEVBDAPP12 -xmlFilePath "C:\Temp\collectors\adcomputer\Discovery.Ser
    vices.ActiveDirectory.Computer.Collector.xml"
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,CreateScheduledTaskFromXML.ps1

What does this mean "Exception calling "RegisterTask" with "6" argument(s): "(1,2)::""
The failure is occuring on the registertask method but the error does not make sense.
This use is based on the following MSDN article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382575(v=vs.85).aspx

As a side not, We cannot update this machine to powershell 3.0 or use the powerpack at this time and would like to avoid schtask.exe so these are not options

If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your aversion to SCHTASK?

Comment: Also, note via this article that if it's a boot trigger in the task the user you pass has to be in the administrators group in the server (remote or local). You could also run with flag 1 rather than 6 to validate syntax without creating the task, to see iff that gives any pointers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382575(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I attempted to use the validate flag (1), along with adding a $null to fullfill the 7 argument as noted in the next post and as specified in the earlier comment and it produced the same error. I changed the type of the GC to string instead of xml and this did not fail with validate.  I then changed the flag back to a 6 and I now get "Exception calling "RegisterTask" with "7" argument(s): "The parameter is inc
orrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))". The question is which one. I will continue to dig on this course of action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out this problem. First was the first argument in the RegisterTask. I was interpreting this as the folder in the Task scheduler. However, this is not the folder but the task name. Second, with the help from some of the comments and the validation flag, I found that the second argument needs to be a string type and not xml type. Finally, I had to add a 7th argument of null to fullfill the method signature: Thanks for all your help

Here is the updated code that works:

```
param(
    [string]$taskName = $(throw "-taskName is required"), #complete path for the scheduled task
    [string]$xmlFilePath = $(throw "-xmlFilePath is required"),
    [string]$server = "localhost", # Only works with Servers it can access. Use WinRM for cross domain request
    [string]$taskFolderName = "\"
)
$value = $null;
try {
    $xmlContent = [string](Get-Content $xmlFilePath);    
    $taskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
    $taskScheduler.Connect($server) 
    $taskFolder = $taskScheduler.GetFolder($taskFolderName);
    $value = $taskFolder.RegisterTask($taskName, $xmlContent, 6, "<username>", "<password>", 1, $null); 
}
catch {

    $Exception = $_.Exception;
    while ($Exception.Message -ne $null)
        {   
           Write-Error $Exception.Message;
           $Exception = $Exception.InnerException;
        }
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just type :

```
$taskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$taskScheduler.Connect("localhost")
$taskFolder = $taskScheduler.GetFolder("\")
$taskFolder.RegisterTask
```

You receive :

```
IRegisteredTask RegisterTask (string, string, int, Variant, Variant, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE, Variant)
```

There are 7 arguments, this meas that you miss one argument. If you have a look at [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the call looks like this :

```
HRESULT RegisterTask(
  [in]            BSTR path,
  [in]            BSTR xmlText,
  [in]            LONG flags,
  [in]            VARIANT userId,
  [in]            VARIANT password,
  [in]            TASK_LOGON_TYPE logonType,
  [in, optional]  VARIANT sddl,
  [out]           IRegisteredTask **ppTask
);
```

So I would try to add $null as the last argument (security descriptor) :

```
$taskFolder.RegisterTask($xmlFilePathl, $xmlContent, 6, "<user name>", "<password>", 1, $null)
```

Comment: I attempted to use 7 arguments along with the $null in the seventh argument but the statement still failed with the same error

Comment: Reading your answer, this one seems to be helpful.